# Let X and Y be independent random variables with X ~ Poisson(5) and Y ~ Bin(6,3/5). Calculate P(X + Y <= 5).

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

So I am meant to calculate this problem using RStudio.  Now, I was thinking that X and Y can be:

1 and 1, 2 and 1, 1 and 2, 2 and 2,... etc.

However, I am not really sure how I would program this into R.  Could someone please help?

Thank you

Comment: (a) they might take the value $0$; (b) the probability mass functions are simple or you can consider the R functions `dbinom`, `dpois`, `pbinom`, `ppois`

Comment: In `R` it's simple as `sum(dpois(0:5,5)*pbinom(5:0,6,3/5))`.